# How can I validate a numeric input in java?

Tags: java, validation, try-catch

I've validated that the entered string is a number.

```
while (true) {

    try {
        numberOfmiles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter Positive Number"));       
         break;
    }

    catch (NumberFormatException nfs) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a Positive number");
    }
}
```

I need to also check that it is a positive number.  How would I do that?

Comment: You could validate it against a regex and make sure only positive numbers are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        while(true){
      String userInput=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter Positive Number");
        if(userInput.matches("^\\d+(.\\d+)?$")){
         double numberOfmiles=Double.parseDouble(userInput);
         if (numberOfmiles <0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning, enter positive numbers only")
        }
        else{
        //successful input
        break;
        }
    }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just positive numbers are allowed"); 
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
double numberOfMiles;
do{
  try{
    numberOfmiles = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter Positive Number"));       
  }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a Positive number");
    numberOfMiles = -1;
  }
}while(numberOfMiles < 0);
```

Comment: This exits the loop when I entered a negative number without showing the error message

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numberOfmiles <0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning, enter positive numbers only");
```

Comment: I also want to check for an String input

Comment: Well they're all strings at the point of entry. It's numerics that you habe to watch out specifically with specialized member functions to do that with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a textfield used as input try this:

```
 private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if ( ((c<'0')||(c>'9'))&& (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE))
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just positive numbers are allowed");                        
        }
else
{
  //non action until a button is pressed
}
```

:)